# Unable to connect to cassandra server on EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I have setup a new EC2 instance to run cassandra on EC2, have gone through bunch of questions that don't seem to help. I am running apache-cassandra-2.1.0-rc3

I have opened port 9160, 9042 on my EC2 instance say its IP address is 1.2.3.4

Since this is single node system I haven't opened other ports as pointed in

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html

When I try to connect to this host using the python driver with cluster config like this:

```
cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['1.2.3.4',], port=9160)
```

I am getting error:

```
 File "....cluster.py", line 1649, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'1.2.3.4': error(111, 'Connection refused')})
```

Any ideas on what incantation I need to have in cassandra.yml file to allow external clients to connect cassandra instance running on EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the cassandra.yaml with this:

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: <your ec2 private ip address>
```

And in your python code you should use the port 9042.

Keep in mind that with this you are opening your cassandra cluster to the internet.